Find a polynomial $p( x )$ if it exist such that $xp( x − 1) = ( x + 1) p( x ).$
It is clear that $p(0) = 0, p(1) = 0, p(2) = 0$ and so on. Similarly, $p(-2) = 0, p(-3) = 0$ and so on. It appears as if $p(x) = 0$, however, I cannot find $p(-1)$.

We know that $p(0) = p(1) = ...$ hence $p(x)$ has infinitely many roots. Thus $p(x) = 0$ for all $x$. And visa versa: if $p(x) = 0$ for all $x$ then the equality from the question holds true.

Thanks. So I do not need to care about $p(-1)$.

@ Shiv yes. You are welcome!

@SergeiNikolaev Beware of finite fields https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187104
